# Workbox: how can I set debug to true in workbox-config.js

Tags: workbox

by default generateSW generates files minified, not useful when you would like to read the generated sw.js file. I found out here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/configure-workbox that one can use

```js
workbox.setConfig({ debug: true });
```

to set debug mode on, this way having sw.js not minified. I was wondering if it's possible to set debug to true in the workbox-config.js file, or at the command line maybe when calling generateSW ?

Many thanks,

Gilles Plante

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`mode: 'development'` option](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#:%7E:text=patterns.-,mode,-Optional) when calling `generateSW`, and it will produce a service worker bundle that includes the extra debugging information.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.

What is this "worker bundle" exactly ? I still get a minified sw.js.

Comment: Ok, got it to work by adding:

module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "build/",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{css,png,html,json,pdf}"
  ],
  "swDest": "build/sw.js",
  "maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes" : 22000000,
  "mode": "development",  <---
  runtimeCaching: [ {
    urlPattern: '/pdf/',
    handler: 'NetworkFirst',
    options: {
      cacheName: 'rtCache'  
    }
  }
  ]
};

inside workbox-config.js !